# List Windows apps in a specific format in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, powershell

To get a list of all installed apps open an elevated PowerShell window and type:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select Name
```

This will produce a list of installed apps. Example:

```
Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
NAVER.LINEwin8
4DF9E0F8.Netflix
```

I need to get a list that does not display the prefix. Example:

```
WindowsCalculator
LINEwin8
Netflix
```

How can I get a list of installed apps without the prefix that precedes the punctuation?

Comment: I don't think you can. The . is a replacement for space, and the name can have more than one space for both the name of the program and the name of the publisher. The Get-Appxpackage does not generate anything else that helps.

Comment: That is a shame, but I realise this is a weird request though...

Comment: You could always split the name on the period, and then take the last member of the resulting array... e.g., if the app name is stored in `$App`, then `($App -split "\.")[-1]` gets you the name after the last period.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your approach literal this will get you the last `.` separated element from the name, but there will be a lot of entries `0,1,2,3,4,6,00,xaml` from apps with appended version information and xaml type:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Select -Expand Name|%{"{0,-40} {1}" -f $_.split(".")[-1],$_}
```

Sample output:

```
BrokerPlugin                             Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin
BioEnrollment                            Microsoft.BioEnrollment
LockApp                                  Microsoft.LockApp
MicrosoftEdge                            Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge
PPIProjection                            Microsoft.PPIProjection
ChxApp                                   Microsoft.Windows.Apprep.ChxApp
AssignedAccessLockApp                    Microsoft.Windows.AssignedAccessLockApp
CloudExperienceHost                      Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost
ContentDeliveryManager                   Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager
Cortana                                  Microsoft.Windows.Cortana
ParentalControls                         Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls
SecondaryTileExperience                  Microsoft.Windows.SecondaryTileExperience
SecureAssessmentBrowser                  Microsoft.Windows.SecureAssessmentBrowser
XboxGameCallableUI                       Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI
ContactSupport                           Windows.ContactSupport
immersivecontrolpanel                    windows.immersivecontrolpanel
MiracastView                             Windows.MiracastView
PrintDialog                              Windows.PrintDialog
3                                        Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.3
3                                        Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.3
3                                        Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3
3                                        Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3
```